# provider value not been assigned

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am just trying to understand what I am missing. I have used Provider state management this way before and it worked but for some reasons I can not see why I keep getting this error :
Exception has occurred.
CastError (Null check operator used on a null value). And I hope someone can help me.

Here is my code. I have a LoginUserProvider class :

```
  class LoginUserProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  UserModel? _userModel;
  SharedPreferences? preferences;
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  DatabaseService databaseService = DatabaseService();

  UserModel? get appUser => _userModel;


    set setLoginUser(UserModel user) {
    _userModel = user;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  

  Future<void> saveDataToFirestore(Map<String, dynamic> data) async {
    User? firebaseUser = _auth.currentUser;
    if (firebaseUser == null) return;

    await databaseService
        .saveUserDataToFirebase(firebaseUser.uid, data)
        .whenComplete(() {
      _userModel = UserModel.fromJson(data);
      // setLoginUser = UserModel.fromJson(data);
      
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

}

My homepage has 3 tabs: Home, Business and Settings. (may be not really relevant but I just want to give as many details as i can)

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> with 
              SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  TabController? _tabController;

  final List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    const HomePage(),
    const BusinessPage(),
    const MySettingsPage()
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController =
        TabController(initialIndex: _selectedIndex, vsync: this, length: 3);
    
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
            physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            controller: _tabController,
            children: _widgetOptions),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'Settings',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The last tab (the settinsPage) has a ListTile that leads to the Customer profile page (and that is where I am getting the error)

```
class MySettinsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MySettinsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Settings'), centerTitle: true,),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children:  [
            ListTile(
              leading: const Icon(Icons.person,),
              title: const Text('User profile'),
              trailing: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
              onTap: (){
                Navigator.push(context, (MaterialPageRoute(builder: ((context) => const 
                 ProfilePage()))));
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
    
  }
}

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Profile Page'), centerTitle: true,),
      body: Consumer<LoginUserProvider>(
        builder: (context, value, child) {
          return ListView(
            children:  [
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('E-mail'),
                subtitle: Text(value.appUser!.email!),
                // The Error is here 
                //the appUser is null
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I have paused the execution and trace the program and I see that my _userModel variable is getting the value after the account is created but I don't understand why is Provider.of(context).appuser is null.

Thanks and sorry for the long question. I don't know how much info might be needed.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue line:** `Text(value.appUser!.email!)`.

`appUser` can be null as declared nullable in the **LoginUserProvider**. And thus you can't say that null can't be null (use of **!** operator on a nullable variable).

**Fix**:

Change `Text(value.appUser!.email!)` to `Text(value.appUser?.email!)`

*or also you can do something like this:*

```
Text(value.appUser != null ? value.appUser!.email! : 'No user')
```

Comment: Thanks. My main concern is why is it "null " since _user Model was already assigned a value?

Comment: value was assigned later but during initialisation, it was declared as nullable which mean it can have value but it can also be null.